# CountDownTimer never stop after call cancel

Tags: android, android-fragments, countdowntimer, illegalstateexception

I have strange problem with `CountDownTimer` object. That mean I using `CountDownTimer` to show message after couple of seconds.

init counter of time:

```
    notLoggedInTimer = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
    //393 line                    
notLoggedInSignUpDialog = SignUpDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.sign_up_dialog_title), new View.OnClickListener() {        
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (!UserDataHelper.getInstance().checkIfLogged(getActivity()))
                                    getActivity().finish();
                            }
                        });
                        notLoggedInSignUpDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), SignUpDialog.TAG);

                    }
                };
                notLoggedInTimer.start();
```

It is initialized in `onViewCreated` fragment. I will call in `onDestory()` method `cancle()` for `CounterDownTimer` object.

After 120000 (2 minutes) I will recevied:

> ```
> > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment
> > WatchStreamLiveFragment{2dae83aa} not attached to Activity 12-15
> > 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:639) 12-15
> > 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:661) 12-15
> > 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > com.vyda.stream.fragments.streaming.WatchStreamLiveFragment$5.onFinish(WatchStreamLiveFragment.java:393)
> > 12-15 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:    
> > at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
> > 12-15 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:    
> > at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 12-15
> > 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 12-15 12:21:32.613
> > 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 12-15
> > 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 12-15 12:21:32.613
> > 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 12-15 12:21:32.613
> > 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
> > 12-15 12:21:32.613 30378-30378/com.vyda.stream E/AndroidRuntime:    
> > at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
> ```

Comment: try changing intialization  from onCreated to onResume and cancel it in onPause

Comment: I can't because i want start once `CounterDownTimer` and display dialog information. If I will change to `onResume` and `onPause` then someone could to call `onResume` and `onPause` every time

Comment: does that mean you only want to call the count down timer once?

Comment: cancel it in onDestroyView